# Show hidden content at bottom of page using tabs on click

Tags: javascript, html, css, tabs

So I have a set of 4 divs at the bottom of my page. I intend for the top of these divs to look like tabs, and when the div (tab) is clicked on, that div's height will increase and thus appear like a hidden page is rising from the bottom of the window.

Here is my code so far:

```
      ---Css---

 tab1 {
   float: left;
   width: 400px;
   height: 100px;
   background: red;
   position: absolute;
   left: 300px;
   bottom: 0px;
   clear:both;
      }

 tab2 {
   width: 400px;
   height: 100px;
   border-radius: 10px 10px 0px 0px;
   background: green;
   position: absolute;
   left: 400px;
   bottom: 0px;
      } 

 tab3 {
   width: 400px;
   height: 100px;
   border-radius: 10px 10px 0px 0px;
   background: red;
   position: absolute;
   left: 500px;
   bottom: 0px;
      }
 tab4 {
   width: 400px;
   height: 100px;
   border-radius: 10px 10px 0px 0px;
   background: green;
   position: absolute;
   left: 600px;
   bottom: 0px;
      }



      ---HTML---

 <tab1></tab1>
 <tab2></tab2>
 <tab3></tab3>
 <tab4></tab4>


     ---JavaScript---
 <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.2/jquery.min.js"type="text/javascript"></script>
<script>

 $('tab1').toggle(function(){
     $(this).animate({'height': '500px'},{speed:10,});
 }, function(){
     $(this).animate({'height': '100px'},{speed:10, });
 });
  $('tab2').toggle(function(){
     $(this).animate({'height': '500px'},{speed:10});
 }, function(){
     $(this).animate({'height': '100px'}, {speed:10});
 });
  $('tab3').toggle(function(){
     $(this).animate({'height': '500px'},{speed:10,});
 }, function(){
     $(this).animate({'height': '100px'},{speed:10, });
 });
 $('tab4').toggle(function(){
     $(this).animate({'height': '500px'},{speed:10});
}, function(){
     $(this).animate({'height': '100px'}, {speed:10});
 });
```

Here is a jsfiddle to demonstrate what I have http://jsfiddle.net/tkTJr/

I want to allow each div to be 100% of the window width but still enable the others to be clicked. At the moment if I did that I can only click on the one with the lowest z-index because they are overlapping. I was thinking of making the top of each div stick out like a tab to differentiate one from another. Any help in doing so?

Many thanks, I hope some one will know the solution to this problem.

Comment: What exactly do you want different? Can you rephrase the sentence "The problem I have is..." to make it more clear?

Comment: I want it so if i make each div 100% page width i can still click on any individual one. at the moment if i did that i could only click on the one with the lowest z-index. I was thinking of make the top of each div stick out like a tab to differentiate one from another.

Comment: What's with the downvotes?  Seems like a legitimate question.  I would probably make the tabs separate from the content and just animate them together.

Comment: I was thinking the same Dmoses, i probably didn't word it the best way though perhaps. I'm pretty experienced with HTML but not so much with Java Script. how would i make it so that the content would increase if the tabs were clicked on, as well as making the tabs rise up the page?

Comment: i tried what you said by using a wrapper and wrapping both the tabs and content area in one div then using the animate function of the wrapper but with no success. perhaps there is a different way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I tried to achieve this using two approaches:

**Approach #1: Javascript/jQuery**

I went ahead and added functionality that closes the 'active' tab as I call it if the user clicks off of the tab's content or tab. Essentially this just toggles the bottom position of the tab and shows/hides (by way of sliding up/down) each time a user clicks a tab. [Here is a live demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Zeaklous/tkTJr/4/) of that. If you're not looking to have the added functionality, [this fiddle will do just fine](http://jsfiddle.net/Zeaklous/tkTJr/3/) for you

Here is the relevant code for the version with increased functionality:

```
<script> // The most important section for you
$('.tab').click(function (e) {
    e.stopPropagation(); // allows the :not to function in the next .click function
    var toggleBot = $(this).css('bottom') == "400px" ? "0px" : "400px"; 
    // ^^ Clever way of toggling between two values
    $(this).animate({
        'bottom': toggleBot // Toggle the value
    });
    var number = $(this).attr('class').split(' ')[1]; // Get the number to relate to the content

    if ($('.active')[0] && number != $('.active').attr('class').split(' ')[1]) {
    // This part makes only one content stay open at a time
        var number2 = $('.active').attr('class').split(' ')[1];
        var toggleBot2 = $('.tab.' + number2).css('bottom') == "0px" ? "400px" : "0px";
        $('.tab.' + number2).animate({
            'bottom': toggleBot2
        });
        $('.content.' + number2).slideToggle().toggleClass('active');
    }
    $('.content.' + number).slideToggle().toggleClass('active');
});
$('.content').click(function(e) { // Again, allows the :not to function correctly below
    e.stopPropagation();
});
$('body:not(.tab, .content)').click(function() { 
// Allows the 'active' tab to be closed when the anything but a tab/content is clicked
    var number2 = $('.active').attr('class').split(' ')[1];
    $('.tab.' + number2).animate({
        'bottom': '0'
    });
    $('.content.' + number2).slideToggle().toggleClass('active');
});
</script>

<style>
div {
    text-align:center;
}
.tab {
    width: 100px;
    height: 50px;
    border-radius: 10px 10px 0px 0px;
    position: absolute; /* !!Important for functionality of tab!! */
    bottom: 0px; /* !!Important for functionality of tab!! */
    z-index:2;
}
.tab.one {
    background: red;
    left:10%;
}
.tab.two {
    background: blue;
    left:30%;
}
.tab.three {
    background: yellow;
    left:50%;
}
.tab.four {
    background:green;
    left:70%;
}
.content {
    border-radius: 10px 10px 0px 0px;
    position:absolute; /* !!Important for functionality of content!! */
    display:none; /* !!Important for functionality of content!! */
    bottom:0; /* !!Important for functionality of content!! */
    left:0px; 
    background:black;
    color:white;
    height:400px;
    width:100%;
    z-index:1;
}
/* Just to add some content */
#mainContent {
    position:relative;
    width:25%;
    height:75%;
    clear:both;
}
</style>

<html> <!-- Note: they are all on the same level -->
<body>
    <div id='#mainContent' style='position:relative; width:75%; height:75%; left:12.5%;'>Zombie ipsum content</div>
    <div class='tab one'>Tab 1</div>
    <div class='content one'>Content 1!</div>
    <div class='tab two'>Tab 2</div>
    <div class='content two'>Content 2!</div>
    <div class='tab three'>Tab 3</div>
    <div class='content three'>Content 3!</div>
    <div class='tab four'>Tab 4</div>
    <div class='content four'>Content 4!</div>
</body>
</html>
```

**Approach #2: CSS**

Before I had toggled width/height with CSS based on `<input>`s and `<label>`s. This time I decided to try to make the same tabs using only CSS, so [here is my attempt](http://jsfiddle.net/Zeaklous/ungNG/4/). Essentially it puts a link around the tab and animates it up when clicked and also animates the content's height when clicked. It took a lot less fiddling to complete and I always love complete CSS projects <3 However this approach does not quite achieve the same functionality as the jQuery approach, which is what I was afraid of and made me sad **:(** The problem is described below in 'Functionality note'

Here is the relevant code for a CSS only approach:

```
//No javascript, Yay!
<style>
div {
    text-align:center;
}
.tab {
    width: 100px;
    height: 50px;
    text-align:center;
    border-radius: 10px 10px 0px 0px;
    color:black;
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0px;
    z-index:2;
}
.tab.one {
    background: red;
    left:10%;
}
.tab.two {
    background: blue;
    left:30%;
}
.tab.three {
    background: yellow;
    left:50%;
}
.tab.four {
    background:green;
    left:70%;
}

 #mainContent {
    position:relative;
    width:25%;
    height:75%;
    clear:both;
}
#wrapper { /* Allows the tabs to be at the bottom */
    position:absolute;
    bottom:0;
    width:100%;
    text-decoration: none;
}
.content {
    border-radius: 10px 10px 0px 0px;
    position:absolute;
    bottom:0;
    left:0px;
    background:black;
    color:white;
    height:0px;
    width:100%;
    z-index:1;
    -webkit-transition:all 1s ease;
    -moz-transition:all 1s ease;
    -ms-transition:all 1s ease;
}
.hideUp {
    display:block;
    position:relative;
    -webkit-transition:all 1s ease;
    -moz-transition:all 1s ease;
    -ms-transition:all 1s ease;
}
.hideUp:focus {
    bottom: 400px;
}
.hideUp:focus + .content {
    height:400px;
}
</style>

<html>
<body>
<div id='#mainContent' style='position:relative; width:75%; height:75%; left:12.5%;'>Zombie ipsum content.</div>
<div id='wrapper'>
    <a href="#" tabindex="-1" class="hideUp"> <!-- Allows the CSS to know whether the tab has focus or not -->
        <div class="tab one">Tab 1</div>
    </a> 
    <div class="content">Content 1</div>

    <a href="#" tabindex="-1" class="hideUp">
        <div class="tab two">Tab 2</div>
    </a>
    <div class="content">Content 2</div>

    <a href="#" tabindex="-1" class="hideUp">
        <div class="tab three">Tab 3</div>
    </a>
    <div class="content">Content 3</div>

    <a href="#" tabindex="-1" class="hideUp">
        <div class="tab four">Tab 4</div>
    </a>
    <div class="content">Content 4</div>
</div>
</body>
</head>
```

**Usage note:** The jQuery approach requires devices be able to run jQuery (of course) and the CSS approach requires that users be on "modern" browsers that allow CSS3 transitions. I didn't include all of the browser tags in my CSS, just the ones for webkit, mozilla, and IE.

**Functionality note:** The CSS approach I used does not allow user to click the tab to 'close' the content, they must click anywhere else. It also allows the tab to close when the content is clicked, so unless someone finds a work around for it it's only functional for displaying static content like images, text, etc.

One could change the CSS demo to only open/close when the tab itself is clicked by using the [checkbox-hack](http://css-tricks.com/the-checkbox-hack/), allowing the content to be selected and such

If you'd like any part of it explained further let me know. I hope I helped!

Comment: Wow, thank you so much Zeaklous. What you have coded is exactly what i was trying to do. Usually i do try to use only HTML5 instead of Javascript as i've not really had much experience with JavaScript. However in this case i think approach 1 would better suit me because of the functionality like you said. I am going to try and work out what the JS does but if you could explain it simply (brief overview)  i would be most greatfull. Ps i've tried to up vote your answer but i don't have enough rep yet. Any way thank you again Zeaklous! :)